# How combine templates in xslt

Tags: xslt

I have two templates. I want to combine them together.

```
<xsl:template match="abc//para/c">
    <p type="ccc">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="abc/c">
    <p type="ccc">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Tried code:

```
<xsl:template match="abc//para/c or abc/c">
    <p type="ccc">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

My tried code is not success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `match="abc//para/c | abc/c"`.